# Why doesn't using a NULL autoPtr terminate the program?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class autoPtr
{
   public:
    autoPtr(T* ptr)
    {
        cout<<"autoPtr ctr"<<endl;
        loc=ptr;
    }

    autoPtr()
    {
        loc=NULL;
        cout<<"autoPtr dflt ctr"<<endl;
    }
    ~autoPtr()
    {
        cout<<"autoPtr dtr"<<endl;
        delete loc;
    }
    //assignment operator
    autoPtr& operator=(autoPtr& rRef)
    {
        cout<<"autoPtr assignment operator"<<endl;
        loc=rRef.loc;
        rRef.loc=NULL;
        return *this;

    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        cout<<"address -"<<loc<<endl;
        return loc;
    }

private:
    T* loc;
};

  class base
  {
    public:
    base()
    {
        cout<<"base ctr"<<endl;
    }
    ~base()
    {
        cout<<"base dtr"<<endl;
    }
    void printHello(int i)
    {
        cout<<"HELLO : "<<i<<endl;
    }
  };

 int main()
 {
  autoPtr<base> ptr(new base());
  autoPtr<base> ptr1;
  ptr1=ptr;
  ptr1->printHello(1);
  ptr->printHello(2);  //should make the program terminate, but not so ?
 }
```

The Question is:

```
ptr->printHello(2);
```

should make the program terminate, but it doesn't. Why not?

Answer (score 8):

Because you are getting lucky.  Your program causes an **Undefined Behavior**.

```
ptr1 = ptr
```

This code assigns NULL address for the first `auto_ptr` object `ptr` and some non-NULL address for the second object `ptr1`, The source object loses the reference during the assignment (=).

While executing the statement:

```
ptr->printHello(2);
```

`ptr` is a `NULL` pointer and dereferencing a NULL pointer is **Undefined Behavior**.

***But since inside the function `printHello()` you do not access any class member variables it works fine. Add a member variable to your class and then try accessing that in the `printHello()` function, you will see that it (most likely)crashes***

It is important to note that **Undefined Behavior** means anything can happen and the behavior cannot be defined in terms of the language specifications in the C++ Standard. In this case the fact that it works doesn't guarantee it always will and it is still an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior means that your program could play Beethoven 5th, launch a nuclear missile and make you lose your job and still conform to the standard. When undefined programs do nothing, this is the worst situation which can happen to you. And this happens quite often actually. Until you have 1000s of lines of UB and you try to add a member variable access to your `printHello` function the day before release. Kaboom !

Answer (score 4):

```
ptr->printHello(2);//should make the program terminate.but not so...y ??
```

Not necessarily. Its actually undefined behavior. Your program will crash if you're lucky.

Undefined behavior doesn't guarantee any *defined* behavior. So you don't know what might happen when executing the above line.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a **BIG** mistake, the sooner you correct it the better your life with C++ will be. The mistake is confusing crashes with errors.

Dereferencing a NULL pointer is "Undefined Behavior". It doesn't mean you will get a runtime error. It doesn't mean your program will crash. It doesn't mean anything useful will happen. It doesn't mean that anything you may hope for will happen.

It means that ANYTHING can happen.

Including nothing.

Actually "nothing" is a pretty common case and also a very dangerous one. Programs keep to apparently work normally even if undefined behavior mistakes are present.

Until of course the big demo day, when they will crash in your face making your show miserable and good only for laughing at it.

And you will start blaming the OS, the compiler, the hardware, the "bad luck" and whatnot.

Undefined behavior, with the addition of C++ complexity and sometimes illogical rules and choices, make the language very dangerous and impossible to learn by experimentation.
Think hard for every C++ line you write. The language untold assumption is that you will never make that kind of mistakes.

There are no "Runtime Error Angels" in C++. Just "Undefined Behavior Daemons".

PS: Your implementation doesn't handle the copy constructor.

Comment: yeah..i know that..that is what i am asking..why is my program not crashing when i am dereferencing a null pointer ?

Comment: Because a daemon is a daemon. And they like to do the worst possible thing to damage you. In this case is just staying silent. Let me repeat... UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR DOESN'T MEAN THE PROGRAM WILL CRASH. Keep repeating this until the concept sticks in your brain. Going out of an array? May be no crash. using an already deleted object? No crash guarantee. Deleting an object twice? No crash guarantee. Using an invalidated iterator? No crash guarantee. Murphy says you will only get a crash when that is going to make the most possible damage for you.

Comment: "If you're hoping for C++0x to fix the problem": here actually it does somewhat. Drop `autoPtr` and use `std::unique_ptr`. Since you explicitly request the move, such errors are less likely to happen by "accident".

Comment: @6502: `i = i++` has always been UB, and anyone writing `i = ++i` should be shot immediately.

Comment: @6502: I don't quite remember the changes that have been made to expression evaluation order, but IIRC the intent was to clarify the previous sequence points stuff.

Comment: @abcd: Jeez, someone goes to the trouble of writing a long, detailed, and correct answer to the question you asked, your response is to say 'yeah I know that' and then demonstrate in your very next sentence that you very definitely don't know. Try reading it again.

Comment: @john: apparently this answer is clearly wrong given that got even downvoted without telling why...

Answer (score 1):

Everyone pointing out that using a NULL pointer is Undefined Behaviour rather than a guaranteed crash is of course 100% right.

However in this case there is something quite specific which makes it **unlikely** that the result here would be a crash: and that is that the `printhello()` method you call is **not** a virtual function. That means that the code to make the call does not in fact need to know an object address: it is (or at least can be, and I believe usually is) linked & called in pretty much the same way as a simple global function.

The object address is of course calculated and passed to the function as the hidden `this` parameter (since it is not a static function), but that does not mean that the function cannot be called. I think if you printed out `this` in `printhello()`  you would see it printing out as 0, but that does not mean that your program will crash.

Of course as the others have pointed out, it is **very** likely to crash as soon as you refer to any member variables, or call any virtual methods (because in that case you are using `this` as a pointer to an object, which it no longer is (an important demo may well also increase the likelihood of a crash!).